# Como evitar ou tratar perda de dados após rodar o comando MIGRATE?

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, migrations

Segunda-feira fiz a inserção de um novo migrate em um projeto, onde era criada uma nova tabela.

Após rodar os comandos no ambiente local e tudo funcionar, atualizei o git do servidor de produção e rodei o PHP ARTISAN MIGRATE como sempre.

Acontece que em uma das minhas tabelas, a maior parte dos dados sumiu (era uma tabela de contas, com cerca de 700 registros).

O resultado do migrate na shell foi o esperado, apensa a inserção da nova tabela e nenhum erro ou informação de que algo teria acontecido com a tabela "contas".

Alguém já sofreu com esse erro? Arrumou uma solução?

Comment: A solução é restaurar um backup em produção e fazer testes em homologação primeiro.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem os seeders configurados e prontos com os dados que haviam na tabela? Se rodar somente o migrate, somente vai recriar o banco. Algumas operações de migração são destrutivas, o que significa que elas podem fazer com que você perca dados. Para proteger você de executar esses comandos em seu banco de dados de produção, você será solicitado a confirmar antes de os comandos serem executados. A menos que tenha usado o sinalizador --force ou o .env não esteja configurado como "production".

Para reverter a operação de migração mais recente, você pode usar o comando rollback. Este comando reverte o último "lote" de migrações, que pode incluir vários arquivos de migração:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

> [Documentação - Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations)

Answer (score 0):

Lamento pelos dados perdidos.

Por padrão, comando migrate só fará o que você definir nos arquivos, sempre rodando os arquivos novos que ainda não foram executados. Com isso em mente, temos que tomar dois cuidados:

1. Nunca alterar o nome dos arquivos das migrations já executadas, eles são a chave para o Laravel entender qual migration já rodou e não repetir nada.
2. Analisar bem se a operação planejada não vai ferir os dados reais, como por exemplo alterar o tipo de dado de uma coluna para um novo que seja incompatível com o anterior.

Em relação ao comando, para casos estruturais, você pode utilizar o `rollback` para retornar a migrate executada.

Outro cuidado importante para ter, é com as Seeders. Se você incluir o parametro `--seed` ao comando na migrate, elas serão executadas conforme definidas no arquivo `DatabaseSeeder.php`. E, claro, você terá dados replicados no seu banco. Para evitar isso, sempre que é possível, eu costumo criar as seeders com `updateOrInsert`, isso previne duplicatas.

Honestamente, eu suponho que possa ter algo diferente na sua migrate que tenha feito essa perda dos dados ou que o problema esteja relacionado a outra coisa. Talvez até outra migrate que foi alterada e re-executou?

Digo isso pois nós temos uma dezenas de API's aqui e todas rodam o comando `php artisan migrate` automaticamente no pipeline de deploy para todos os nossos ambientes sem medo de quebrar as coisas. E não temos tanto medo dessas situações, não parece ser algo muito comum, por isso faço a pergunta: Será que o problema realmente foi essa 'migrate' específica que você está pensando?

Agora para solucionar seu caso, eu acredito que somente restaurando os dados mesmo a partir de algum backup.

É possível que tenhamos alguma coisa relacionada que possua algum `delete` com `cascade` nessa situação?